# Import images into js file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I am using Play 2.4.2 version. In one of my javascript file, I am writing dynamic html which has an `<img>` tag. My images are placed inside the `public/images` and my javascript file is in `public/javascripts`

I tried all the below ways and the image is not being rendered in the UI, despite showing the following error in the browser console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

<a href="" ><img src="../images/test.png"/></a>

<a href=""><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/test.png")"/></a>

<a href=""><img src="public/images/test.png/></a>
```

How to ensure that image is properly rendered?

Comment: Try `<a href=""><img src="/assets/images/test.png"></a>` or `<a href=""><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/test.png")"/></a>`

Comment: <img src="/assets/images/test.png"> this is working.

Comment: @Salem using `<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/test.png")"/>` requires the js file to be compiled - if it's just written out that way into the DOM, the browser won't know what to do with it.